# reading from bmp and writing to another bmp file, bytearray index error

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, bitmap

```
BMP_LOCATION = 10
NO_BYTES = 3    
def image_gray(in_file, out_file):
        in_file.seek(BMP_LOCATION)
        data_start = int.from_bytes(in_file.read(4), "little")
        in_file.seek(0)
        header = in_file.read(data_start)
        out_file.write(header)
        pixel = bytearray(in_file.read(NO_BYTES))
        pixel1 = pixel[0]
        pixel2 = pixel[1]
        pixel3 = pixel[2]
        while len(pixel) > 0:
            grays = (pixel1*0.33) + (pixel2*0.6) + (pixel3*0.06)
            grays_int = int(grays)
            gray_pixel = bytearray([grays_int, grays_int, grays_int])
            out_file.write(gray_pixel)
            pixel = bytearray(in_file.read(NO_BYTES))
            pixel1 = pixel[0] # these last 3 index lines are the problem
            pixel2 = pixel[1]
            pixel3 = pixel[2]
        return
```

I'm trying to take a bmp image and make it grayscale by reading the colours from the original and writing out the converted grayscale to a new image. However, when I try to run the program, I get an index error saying the index for the bytearray is out of range. Why is this? Shouldn't each new read inside the while loop still bring back a byte array with indices [0, 1, 2]?

Answer (score 0):

```
BMP_LOCATION = 10
NO_BYTES = 3
def image_gray(in_file, out_file):
    in_file.seek(BMP_LOCATION)
    data_start = int.from_bytes(in_file.read(4), "little")
    in_file.seek(0)
    header = in_file.read(data_start)
    out_file.write(header)
    pixel = bytearray(in_file.read(NO_BYTES))
    while len(pixel) > 0:
        pixel1 = pixel[0] # was doing this twice previously
        pixel2 = pixel[1]
        pixel3 = pixel[2]
        grays = (pixel1*0.33) + (pixel2*0.6) + (pixel3*0.06)
        grays_int = int(grays)
        gray_pixel = bytearray([grays_int, grays_int, grays_int])
        out_file.write(gray_pixel)
        pixel = bytearray(in_file.read(NO_BYTES))
    return
```

After staring at the code for a while I realized there was no reason to assign variables to each indexed value both before and inside the while loop. I moved the variable assignment within the while loop and solved my problem.